# SignalR triggering events client-side in MVC3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I have an invoice importer hub like so:

```
public class ImporterHub : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{

    public void InvoiceImported(InvoiceImportedMessage message)
    {
        Clients["importer"].InvoiceImported(message);
    }

    public void FileImported(FileImportedMessage message)
    {
        Clients["importer"].FileImported(message);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Disconnect()
    {
        return Clients["importer"].leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Connect()
    {
        return Clients["importer"].joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
    {
        return Clients["importer"].rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'm capturing events for a long-running import process like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                model.NotificationRecipient = model.NotificationRecipient.Replace(';', ',');
                ImportConfiguration config = new ImportConfiguration()
                {
                    BatchId = model.BatchId,
                    ReportRecipients = model.NotificationRecipient.Split(',').Select(c => c.Trim())
                };
                var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ImporterHub>();
                context.Groups.Add(this.Session.SessionID, "importer");
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(foo => LaunchFileImporter(config));
                Log.InfoFormat("Queued the ImportProcessor to process invoices.  Send Notification: {0} Email Recipient: {1}",
                    model.SendNotification, model.NotificationRecipient);
                TempData["message"] = "The import processor job has been started.";
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Failed to properly queue the invoice import job.", ex);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            }
        }

    private void LaunchFileImporter(ImportConfiguration config)
    {
        using (var processor = new ImportProcessor())
        {
            processor.OnFileProcessed += new InvoiceFileProcessing(InvoiceFileProcessingHandler);
            processor.OnInvoiceProcessed += new InvoiceSubmitted(InvoiceSubmittedHandler);
            processor.Execute(config);
        }
    }

    private void InvoiceSubmittedHandler(object sender, InvoiceSubmittedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ImporterHub>();
        var message = new InvoiceImportedMessage()
        {
            FileName = e.FileName,
            TotalErrorsInFileProcessed = e.TotalErrors,
            TotalInvoicesInFileProcessed = e.TotalInvoices
        };
        context.Clients["importer"].InvoiceImported(message);
    }
    private void InvoiceCollectionSubmittedHandler(object sender, InvoiceCollectionSubmittedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void InvoiceFileProcessingHandler(object sender, InvoiceFileProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ImporterHub>();
        var message = new FileImportedMessage()
        {
            FileName = e.FileName
        };
        context.Clients["importer"].FileImported(message);
    }
```

I have the following script in my view for the importer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var importerHub = jQuery.connection.importerHub;

    importerHub.InvoiceImported = function (message) {
        jQuery('#' + message.FileName + '_Invoices').text(message.TotalInvoicesInFileProcessed);
        jQuery('#' + message.FileName + '_Errors').text(message.TotalErrorsInFileProcessed);
    };

    importerHub.FileImported = function (message) {
        jQuery('#' + message.FileName + '_Processed').text('Done');
    };

    jQuery.connection.hub.start();
</script>
```

**What I expected to happen:**

I was expecting the server side events to trigger, which would send messages to the client,
which would, in turn, fire events to update the status of the import process.

**What seems to be happening:**

All server-side events trigger, all is well.  The signalR library seems to initialize properly, but the events never fire, and I never get the updates to appear on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?  This is my first attempt to use the signalR library, so it's entirely possible I'm doing everything wrong.

Comment: in the controller, does it make any difference if you remove the `["importer"]` parameter, i.e. `context.Clients.InvoiceImported("message");`

Comment: I tried that, thanks; it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: SessionID? Why are you passing the SessionID to Groups.Add? That's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* your problem is that your client side hub events are named with init-caps and the default behavior of SignalR is to translate those to init-lower when publishing to the client to align with common JavaScript conventions. Try changing your hub event registrations to this:

```
importerHub.invoiceImported = function (message) {
```

AND

```
importerHub.fileImported = function (message) {
```

Comment: I did change this, and it seems the event fires now.  Now all I have to do is figure out why it's not updating my DOM.  Thanks!